GitHub Actions with Terraform - Multiple Azure subscriptions
TLDR;

End goal: Manage cloud resources across subscriptions in Azure with Terraform, through Github Actions (on pull requests and main branch pushes)

We are using terraform to manage our cloud infrastructure across multiple Azure subscriptions (in the same tenant). We're currently storing our state in a storage account in Azure as well. We can provision all resources across the subscriptions from a local computer without issue after running az login and logging on to the "main" subscription.
Here is the config for our providers.tf:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "= 4.7.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "redacted"
    storage_account_name = "redacted"
    container_name       = "terraform-state"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }

}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

# Main subscription here, holding the storage and the state
provider "azurerm" {
  use_oidc        = true
  client_id       = var.azure_1_client_id
  client_secret   = var.azure_1_client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.azure_1_tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.azure_1_subscription_id
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "2"
  use_oidc        = true
  client_id       = var.azure_2_client_id
  client_secret   = var.azure_2_client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.azure_2_tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.azure_2_subscription_id
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "3"
  use_oidc        = true
  client_id       = var.azure_3_client_id
  client_secret   = var.azure_3_client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.azure_3_tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.azure_3_subscription_id
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "4"
  use_oidc        = true
  client_id       = var.azure_4_client_id
  client_secret   = var.azure_4_client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.azure_4_tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.azure_4_subscription_id
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "5"
  use_oidc        = true
  client_id       = var.azure_5_client_id
  client_secret   = var.azure_5_client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.azure_5_tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.azure_5_subscription_id
  features {}
}

This configuration works really well when creating resources by simply specifying the provider in each resource, example:
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "2" {
  provider                     = azurerm.2
  name                         = "2"

(all names and ids are redacted, but the structure remains.
When we're running the terraform plan locally it works like a charm. But we'd like to move this into a GitHub actions pipeline, for automation.
This is an example of our workflow yml:
name: Terraform Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  TF_VERSION: 1.10.3

permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: Terraform Init, Validate, Plan
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
    - uses: azure/login@v2
      with:
        client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
        subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
    
    - name: Set up Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        terraform_version: ${{ env.TF_VERSION }}

    - name: Terraform Format
      run: terraform fmt -check -recursive

    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init

    - name: Terraform Validate
      run: terraform validate

    - name: Terraform Plan
      run: terraform plan -out=tfplan

I have created an app registration called terraform_runner that has been given the IAM role of "Owner" in each and all subscriptions. I have then taken that app registration's CLIENT_ID, the SUBSCRIPTION_ID of my "main" subscription, and the TENANT_IDof my only tenant and set them as repository secrets within the Github repo.
I have been battling through a bunch of error messages in the terraform init stage of my pipeline, here is the latest one:
│ Error: Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).
│ 
│ To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'
│ auth method - instructions for which can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret
│ 
│ Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.

Can someone please give me some input in how I can get the workflow running so I can automate my terraform stages?

Did you try using the service principle based authentication in the provider @springsomfan

I was afraid that this method would overwrite my authentication for each subscription, turns out that it didn't I had to set workflow global env variables ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_TENANT_ID and ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID. Thanks a bunch for pointing me in the right direction!

I had to set workflow global env variables ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_TENANT_ID and ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, and also find a way to ingest my secrets into my workflow file. Once I had changed the service principal I was logging in with, and set the variables instead of using the azure login step, it worked.
Thanks to @VijayB for pointing me in the right direction.
